# (Deno) How can I execute on the client some functions that were constructed on the server? (event listeners, rerendering functions, etc)

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

I'm working on a UI Element rendering library (sort of like competition to JSX). A big difference is the tool's syntax. I'm using curried functions and a proxy to achieve a "functional" look like so: `a.div(...classes)(...children)`. So far, static SSR rendering is finished, now I'm working on making reactive elements. I plan to create a .json file containing the relations between the elements and the data they react to. Along with the Re-rendering functions, event listeners, and other scripts that run in the client.

I'm planning to use a custom Observable class for rerendering and a function in the API of the renderer for event listeners, like so: `a.div(...classes)(...children).on({ ...eventListeners })`. But how can I send these functions to be executed on the client? It's a really weird question that I'm having a hard time googling, I hope the explanation was clear. Thank you

Edit:
Just for adding context, this is my design for rerendering:
Unlike React that creates a virtual dom, my plan is to link the elements and the data they react to with a little static json. It would look something like:

```js
// static json that connects elements to state data:
[{
 reactant: 'count', // name of the state variable
 rerender: 'child'  // the type of rerendering to be performed
}, ...]

// This is how the server will render the html template:
state = {
  count: 0
}
createApp(state => a.span('label')(state.count))

// This is what the server will send to the client:
'<span data-ref="1">0</span>'
```

The template contains an attribute that wasn't declared: `data-ref="1"` This means that the element's reactiveness is linked to the first entry of the json. The one that states that will react to the state variable 'count' and will rerender only its children. This is very important because it avoids all of the "magic" react has that inefficiently renders elements with a virtual dom.

Comment: If all your rendering code also runs on the client, the client should already have the code right? The way React would do this is that the events arent bound server-side, but the code is run _again_ client-side where the events are bound, and react will not re-render what it doesn't have to. There's a lot of magic to make this happen but this is roughly how that works.

Comment: Yes, but all of the rendering runs on the server. The server renders a complete HTML page and sends it to the client with all static files like css, json, and hopefully a js file with the listeners and rerenders.

Comment: You just said you 'rerender' on the client, so you don't just render on the server.

Comment: Rerendering in this context is not using a virtual dom to render everything again. It uses the references it builds to only alter the parts of the client that are needed for the interaction to happen. For example, in a simple counter app: React rerenders everything in a virtual dom, then checks what needs to be updated and does it. In my design there is no virtual dom. When rendering the initial html template, I would like to just change the counter display's content from 0 to 1 when clicked a button, not by using a virtual dom. Is this explanation clearer? I also added an edit

Comment: So you *can* stringify functions, but this would get quite complex if those functions call other functions and modules. So as long as your event handlers are simple inline functions this might work, otherwise this is going to be quite a difficult problem to solve.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, discussing this with you was really helpful. I'll test the stringify function solution you propose, maybe I can get it to work somehow.

Comment: @OscarAlfonsoGuerrero cool! did you ever end up pushing something to GitHub? I'm experimenting with something very, very similar: https://github.com/mb21/mastro (down to the [html syntax](https://github.com/mb21/mastro/blob/main/libs/html.ts))